# What is the present state of research on the theory of the size and shape of nations?

Tags: reference-request, economic-history

I recently discovered interesting research from [D. Friedman, titled A Theory of the Size and Shape of Nations,](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1828329) where the size and shape of nations is being explained through economic factors.

However, the research is already quite old. What is the current state of research on this topic? Are there any literature reviews?